# Pack recommendations for running?

Tags: backpacks

So I've been running to work as my form of commuting and I've been getting by with my Gregory Z45 internal-frame pack for carrying whatever I need for the day.  What bothers me about this pack is that it seems to flop around quite a bit when running, which gets to be annoying over the course of the 6 miles to my office.

Ideally, I think I'm looking for something really simple and lightweight that would sit nicely between my shoulderblades while still being secured by some sort of a hip strap.  I'd also love to be able to take such a pack out for some lightweight backpacking, so a frame isn't strictly necessary since I'd use a sleeping pad for some structure in this case.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Is there more definition that you would like to add the the original question  in hopes of a different answer? or is the current answer what you were looking for?

Comment: @MaskedPlant No, the current answer is sufficient ... I just hadn't checked out this question in a while.

Comment: No worries, James. Hope you've been able to get Outdoors while out of the office. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had very good success with the [Osprey Talon Series](http://www.ospreypacks.com/en/group/multi-use/talon_series) of packs. I personally own the 22 and the 44. Both are good packs that meet the requirements that you have outlined in your second paragraph.